# Android - error opening trace file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtime, android-mediaplayer

I'm getting a weird list of errors, some seemingly disconnected but I have no way to tell as I can't even get my App to load to debug.  It's a very simple app, 3 radio buttons in a radio group and each one will trigger a different song to play.

I will start by posting my Manifest, my activity file, and layout then post the error log.

Manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cis298.lab2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity 
            android:label = "@string/app_name"
            android:name = ".LayoutActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
            ></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LayoutActivity:

```
package com.cis298.lab2;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.cis298.lab2.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class LayoutActivity extends Activity {

    int song;
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, song);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        try {
            mediaplayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RadioGroup radgrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        radgrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId){
                case R.id.dance:
                    song = R.raw.redalert;
                    mediaplayer.start();
                    break;
                case R.id.rap:
                    song = R.raw.cannedheat;
                    break;
                case R.id.rock:
                    song = R.raw.movmou8105;
                    break;}
            }
        });
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <RadioGroup
       android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/rock"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Play Rock" />

       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/rap"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Play Rap" 
           android:checked="true"/>

       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/dance"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Play Dance"
           android:textAlignment="center" />

   </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Log:

> 02-21 20:34:05.044: D/AndroidRuntime(322): Shutting down VM 02-21
>   20:34:05.044: W/dalvikvm(322): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 02-21 20:34:05.094:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-21 20:34:05.094:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.cis298.lab2/com.cis298.lab2.LayoutActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 02-21 20:34:05.094:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>   02-21 20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   02-21 20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 02-21
>   20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   02-21 20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-21
>   20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 02-21 20:34:05.094:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 02-21
>   20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-21
>   20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 02-21 20:34:05.094:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   02-21 20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 02-21
>   20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-21 20:34:05.094:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(322): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 02-21
>   20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
>   02-21 20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:641) 02-21
>   20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at
>   com.cis298.lab2.LayoutActivity.(LayoutActivity.java:15) 02-21
>   20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 02-21 20:34:05.094:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429) 02-21 20:34:05.094:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   02-21 20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
>   02-21 20:34:05.094: E/AndroidRuntime(322):    ... 11 more

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You havent initialized something in your activity. thats all i can say from this!

Comment: What is line 15 of LayoutActivity.java?

Comment: BTW There was an extra > before I the close activity tag which I removed and I am still getting the same erros.

Comment: Line 15 is 
 MediaPlayer mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, song);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving   `mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, song);` to inside `onCreate()`.

Since the Activity isn't fully initialized until `onCreate()`, this may be the cause of the NPE.

***However***, the next problem is that you create the MediaPlayer with song being initially `0` (int has a default value of `0` when it is an instance variable). So if moving `MediaPlayer.create` solves *this* NPE, the next error will be something about not being able to find the resource. Therefore, call `MediaPlayer.create` once `song` holds on to something **useful**.

Maybe something like this will work.

```
public class LayoutActivity extends Activity {

  int song;
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    RadioGroup radgrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    radgrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId){
          case R.id.dance:
            song = R.raw.redalert;
            break;
          case R.id.rap:
            song = R.raw.cannedheat;
            break;
          case R.id.rock:
            song = R.raw.movmou8105;
            break;
        }


        mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(LayoutActivity.this, song);
        try {
          mediaplayer.prepare();
          mediaplayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And if song isn't used anywhere else, you can keep it in the scope of `onCheckedChanged()`.

Comment: This was my issue (having to move it into the onCreate method).  Also, it is taking me 5+ minutes to upload the APK everytime.  I looked into it and people were complaining about 90 seconds so something must be really wrong, any idea?

Comment: We've all been new, and your question was nice and detailed :-) with new users, I always link to that meta question if they said my answer right since not all are familiar with how all of SO works. Anyways, welcome!